# where is all the financial data published: symbols, earnings yield, return on capital

Tags: united-states, canada, nyse, toronto-stock-exchange

How does one get their hands on publicly-traded company financials? is there an official repository for this?

- i’d be interesting in looking at the list of available stock symbols
- a company’s earnings yield (or P/E ratio)
- a company’s return on invested capital (ROIC)
- other

There’s all these historical simulations out there, where is the data coming from?

(toronto stock exchange tsx, nyse)

Answer (score 2):

Public companies trading on stock exchanges are required to publish their financial reports. In the US, the SEC (the regulator) has a database for all these publications (called "SEC filings") called [EDGAR](https://www.sec.gov/edgar/search-and-access). In Canada similarly [SEDAR](https://www.sedar.com/homepage_en.htm). Other information (like stock prices and market capitalisation) comes from the exchanges themselves. Many times you'll need to pay for access depending on volume and freshness of the information you need.